# Preferred style for referencing other objects in REDIS

Tags: coding-style, redis

What is preferred style when referencing other objects in REDIS?

Lets say I have an object with IDs like `my_obj_type:123`, and I have a homogeneous list of such a objects. What is preferred style, should list contain IDs like `my_obj_type:123` or rather `123`?

Answer (score 1):

It should contain 123. Rationale:

- It is more compact in memory.
- Adding back the prefix to the key to access the main object is trivial.
- Redis has a number of optimizations that only apply if the data is a numeric value. This is especially true if you plan to use sets (managed internally as intsets).

See http://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization for more information.

Comment: Ok, fair points on optimizations, +1 for that. But that doesn't really answer style question.